# How to make Enter on a TextBox act as TAB button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've several textboxes. I would like to make the Enter button act as Tab. So that when I will be in one textbox, pressing Enter will move me to the next one. Could you please tell me how to implement this approach without adding any code inside textbox class (no override and so on if possible)?

Comment: Is this a web or a win forms application?

Comment: I found this http://www.surpluscode.com/2006/06/15/winforms-process-enter-key-press-as-tab-via-sendkeyssend/

Comment: This feels a bit hacky to me :)

Comment: It sounds hacky, but this worked for me. GetNextControl() don't take into account that some controls on Form can be invisible or disabled. I've tried to do something like this, but it's not so easy. So I'll use this solution. Thank you Pharabus!

Comment: I am also this query. Thanks for asking..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is the code that I usually use.
It must be on KeyDown event.

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Other way is sending "TAB" key! And overriding the method make it so easier :)

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{            
    if (keyData == (Keys.Enter))
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: +1 I think `SelectNextControl` is better then `GetNextControl` because this will automatically skip Label, Panel, GroupBox, PictureBox, ProgressBar, Splitter and LinkLabel. More information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol.aspx

Comment: +1 Because `SelectNextControl` makes the _Enter_ key behave more like _Tab_ key here, as it will also skip controls where `TabStop` is set to `false`, if third argument is set to `true`.

Comment: This answer is so close, it has all the code you need, but split across two code snippets.  You want to call SelectNextControl instead of SendKeys.Send("{TAB}") inside the "ProcessCmdKey" override.  Also, ProcessCmdKey should return true in that case, so it won't keep processing the enter key keypress.  Also, you need to set KeyPreview = true for the ProcessCmdKey to get called.

Answer (score 12):

You can write on the **keyDown** of any control:

```
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {

            if (this.GetNextControl(ActiveControl, true) != null)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                this.GetNextControl(ActiveControl, true).Focus();

            }
        }
```

GetNextControl doesn't work on [Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getnextcontrol(VS.80).aspx).

To make it work with Vista you will need to use the code below to replace the this.GetNextControl...:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

Comment: GetNextControl does not work in Windows 10 either. Use SendKeys.Send("{TAB}").

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to make an "enter event handler"

All you need to do is make a "central" KeyDown event:

example

```
private void General_KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {

            if (this.GetNextControl(ActiveControl, true) != null)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                this.GetNextControl(ActiveControl, true).Focus();
            }
        }
}
```

Then all you have to do is go to designer select all textboxes you wish to cycle through with EnterKey (select them by holding down Ctrl and clicking on textbox with the mouse) then go to Events(thunder like button), search Keydown event and type inside General_KeyDown. Now all your selected Textboxes will have the same keydown event :) This makes everything muuuuch much easier, cause imagine a form with 100 textboxes and you want to cycle through all with enter.... making an apart event for each texbox is... well not a proper way to make a program, it ain't neat. Hope it helped!!

> Blockquote

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            ((TextBox)sender).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(new FocusNavigationDirection()));
```

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to cast it to `TextBox`. Instead cast it to `UIElement`, then you can use this method on every control. Also you should mention that this is only available in WPF and not in Winforms.

Comment: @Oliver: +1 for mentioning it's only available for WPF, not for winforms.

Answer (score 3):

It is important to note that if you will get an annoying "ding" or warning sound each time that the control is expecting an associated button control and `e.Handled = true` isn't always the answer to rid yourself of the noise/sound/ding.

If the control (i.e. single-line textbox) is expecting an associated button to 'ENTER' your entry, then you must also deal with the 'missing' control.

```
e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```

This may be helpful when getting rid of the 'ding' sound.

For what it's worth- in my circumstance my users needed to use the "ENTER KEY" as we were transitioning from a terminal/green-screen application to a windows app and they were more used to "ENTER-ing" through fields rather than tabbing.

All these methods worked but still kept the annoying sound until I added `e.SuppressKeyPress`.

Answer (score 2):

If you define Tab Order of all controls and make Form.KeyPreview = True, only need this:

```
    Private Sub frmStart_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code in one of the text box keydown event

```
if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
{
     e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
     SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
}
```

Unable handle this `keydown` event for all text boxes in my form. Suggest something. Thanks

Comment: I write this code in form load but it didn't work     foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control cont in this.Controls)
                {
                    if (cont is TextBox)
                    {
                        cont.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.txtNo_KeyDown);
                    }

Answer (score 1):

I don't do it at the form level. I create a single method that I share across all my inputs KeyDown event that I want to do this with (with one exception):

```
       private void alltextBoxes_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);                    
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

If I'm writing a control that I want to use in other applications, I give the last input its own method like this:

```
       private void lastinput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, the control just loops inside itself when you try to run it in another project. You could use the second way everywhere but I think the 1st is the preferred way.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that code in vb...

```
Public Class NoReturnTextBox
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

    Const CARRIAGE_RETURN As Char = Chr(13)

    ' Trap for return key....
    Private Sub NoReturnTextBox_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

        If e.KeyChar = CARRIAGE_RETURN Then
            e.Handled = True
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(vbTab)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I use for VB.NET

1. Set **Keypreview=True** in your form properties.
2. Put this code in form keydown event:

   If (e.KeyData = Keys.Enter) Then

   'for any multiline control, you have to exit to let multiline                  'textbox intro 'keypressing makes line skips.

   ```
    If ActiveControl.Name = txtMyMutilineTextBox.Name Then Exit Sub 

    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, True, True, True, True)
   ```

   End If

**Enjoy !!!!**

**Xabier Aberasturi Larruzea**

Answer (score 0):

This is better because when enter u can do focus the next tab.. U need setting TAB Order first

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == (Keys.Enter))
            {
                SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);
            }

            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Taking a wild guess:

```
// on enter event handler
parentForm.GetNextControl().Focus();
```

Answer (score -1):

I would combine what Pharabus and arul answered like this:

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
if (e.KeyChar == ‘\r’)
{
e.Handled = true;
parentForm.GetNextControl().Focus()
}
}
```

Let me know if this helps!  JFV