# Press Enter to move to next control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a few TextBox on the WinForm. I would like the focus to move to the next control when Enter key is pressed? Whenever a textbox gains control, it will also select the text, so that any editing will replace the current one.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Tab as Enter: create a user control which inherits textbox, override the `KeyPress` method.  If the user presses enter you can either call `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")` or `System.Windows.Forms.Control.SelectNextControl()`. Note you can achieve the same using the `KeyPress` event.

Focus Entire text: Again, via override or events, target the `GotFocus` event and then call `TextBox.Select` method.

Comment: Sending key strokes is not the best solution when a method is provided to accomplish the task. [SelectNextControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol.aspx) can perform the same function as sending the tab button without the messiness of sending keys.

Answer (score 33):

A couple of code examples in C# using **SelectNextControl**.

The first moves to the next control when ***ENTER*** is pressed.

```
    private void Control_KeyUp( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
    {
        if( (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return) )
        {
            this.SelectNextControl( (Control)sender, true, true, true, true );
        }
    }
```

The second uses the ***UP*** and ***DOWN*** arrows to move through the controls.

```
    private void Control_KeyUp( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
    {
        if( e.KeyCode == Keys.Up )
        {
            this.SelectNextControl( (Control)sender, false, true, true, true );
        }
        else if( e.KeyCode == Keys.Down )
        {
            this.SelectNextControl( (Control)sender, true, true, true, true );
        }
    }
```

See MSDN [SelectNextControl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol.aspx)

Comment: My favorite answer. This assumes that the developer has correctly set the TabStop & TabIndex properties for the controls which they should always do.

Comment: If you want to apply this on all controls of the current form, you can set the forms property KeyPreview to True, register to the KeyUp event of the form and replace "(Control)sender" with "ActiveControl" in the code above.

Answer (score 11):

In a `KeyPress` event, if the user pressed Enter, call

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
```

Nicest way to implement automatically selecting the text on receiving focus is to create a subclass of `TextBox` in your project with the following override:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnGotFocus(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    SelectionStart = 0
    SelectionLength = Text.Length
    MyBase.OnGotFocus(e)
End Sub
```

Equivalent C# code:

```cs
protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
{
    SelectionStart = 0;
    SelectionLength = Text.Length;
    base.OnGotFocus(e);
}
```

Then use this custom TextBox in place of the WinForms standard `TextBox` on all your Forms.

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `KeyPress` handler on your TextBoxes, and see which key was used.

To handle the text selection, put a handler on the `GotFocus` event.

You may also want to consider how to (or if you need to) handle multi-line TextBoxes.

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //
    // Detect the KeyEventArg's key enumerated constant.
    //
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed enter! Good job!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void txt_invoice_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            txt_date.Focus();
    }

    private void txt_date_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            txt_patientname.Focus();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could also write your own Control for this, in case you want to use this more often.
Assuming you have multiple TextBoxes in a Grid, it would look something like this:

```
public class AdvanceOnEnterTextBox : UserControl
{

    TextBox _TextBox;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(String), typeof(AdvanceOnEnterTextBox), null);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputScopeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InputScope", typeof(InputScope), typeof(AdvanceOnEnterTextBox), null);


    public AdvanceOnEnterTextBox()
    {
        _TextBox = new TextBox();
        _TextBox.KeyDown += customKeyDown;
        Content = _TextBox;

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Text for the TextBox
    /// </summary>
    public String Text
    {
        get { return _TextBox.Text; }
        set { _TextBox.Text = value; }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Inputscope for the Custom Textbox
    /// </summary>
    public InputScope InputScope
    {
        get { return _TextBox.InputScope; }
        set { _TextBox.InputScope = value; }
    }


    void customKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter)) return;

        var element = ((TextBox)sender).Parent as AdvanceOnEnterTextBox;
        if (element != null)
        {
            int currentElementPosition = ((Grid)element.Parent).Children.IndexOf(element);
            try
            {
                // Jump to the next AdvanceOnEnterTextBox (assuming, that Labels are inbetween).
                ((AdvanceOnEnterTextBox)((Grid)element.Parent).Children.ElementAt(currentElementPosition + 2)).Focus();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Close Keypad if this was the last AdvanceOnEnterTextBox
                ((AdvanceOnEnterTextBox)((Grid)element.Parent).Children.ElementAt(currentElementPosition)).IsEnabled = false;
                ((AdvanceOnEnterTextBox)((Grid)element.Parent).Children.ElementAt(currentElementPosition)).IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do this of course, however, having a single method on form is much easier than re-writing all the controls you are going to use which will lead to having a massive codebase, and debugging them later.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Enter))
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

goto the design form and View-> tab(as like picture shows) Order then you ordered all the control[That's it]
[image]

Comment: code get from Behzad (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371329/how-to-make-enter-on-a-textbox-act-as-tab-button)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use:

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
```