# Navigation in Windows Forms using enter key

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, uinavigationcontroller

I have textboxes in my Windows Forms application, and I want that when the user presses the ENTER key then the cursor goes to the next textbox.

How do I do this?

Is this a good habit or shall I avoid it? Actually the users are very much prone and have adapted and have become habitual of pressing ENTER key for navigation between textboxes and buttons. So, for them I need to do this.

Please help me with the complete code using two text-boxes as an example.

Comment: it all depends of your requirement

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Press Enter to move to next control on a WinForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087786/c-press-enter-to-move-to-next-control-on-a-winform)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say the nicest way is to create a user control that inherits from TextBox and then override the OnKeyPress method to capture enter and send a tab. Focus will then be given to the next TabIndex on the form, just as though a tab had actually been entered.

The code below does exactly that:

```
public partial class CustomTextbox : TextBox
{
    public CustomTextbox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        }

    }
}
```

You could also put similar code in the KeyPress event handlers for your controls but this saves a lot of duplicate code and unnececessary event handler.

As for whether this is good practice - I would say in general, no, changing the default behaviour of forms is never a good idea, but of course, if this is what your users want and expect, then it is their decision.

Comment: sir, do controls like text-boxes or buttons do not have OnKeyPress method? when i wrote button1. and checked out in the IntelliSense , then there's no such method? why so?

Comment: so , according to you, i shall first create a new project of user control in visual studio and put your code , and use that control in other winform projects by adding it in the ToolBox?

Comment: also, sir, there's no OnKeyPress event when i see in the Properties of a textbox by pressing F4 key.

Comment: @sqlchild I'm not sure what your question is here. All controls have the OnKeyPress method - but it is a protected method of the Control class which they inherit from. So to do anything with this you either need to override the method as I have shown (in a control the inherits from TextBox for example), or handle the KeyPress method.

Comment: @sqlchild - for now you don't need a new project, just a new usercontrol which inherits from textbox - and yes, you add it to your ToolBox. And sorry, I should have written KeyPress eventhandler.

Comment: @sqlchild: and am i right for that, that i have to create a new project, windows control library in VS and add your code?

Comment: ok sir, so i shall do this : Project-->Add User Control in my existing project?

Comment: @sqlchild: No, your don't *need* a new project, only if you want to reuse this control in several projects. All you need do is add a new usercontrol to the project and then change the class it inherits from to textbox. I had to also remove one line of autogenerated code to make it compile.

Comment: Sir, when i added a User Control then in the code the line was :     public partial class CustomTextbox : UserControl, but as your code, i changed it to :    public partial class CustomTextbox : TextBox
But its giving error when i compile it:'MyProject.CustomTextBox.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override , but again changing it to previous one din't remove the error, the error is in CustomTextBox.Designer.cs file

Comment: @sqlchild you probably have a mismatch in class names between the CustomTextbox and the designer, so the partial class is not working, and thus the override of dispose in the designer fails. Double check that the class names match.

Comment: thank your sir, it worked , also, am having a button , now enter key won't press the button , its just used for navigation. but if i want that the Enter key also presses the button , i.e. from textbox on pressing the enter key the tab goes to the button , and on the button when again the key is pressed then it should press the button? is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bad idea. The standard UI is for TAB to move between input fields. You make your app less useable when you elect not to follow well known standards. These standards are what makes UI intuitive.

Comment: Heffeman : sir, can you refer me some book or links where its written that its a bad idea to play with the RETURN key. actually i need to show it to my boss, that its really a bad one

Comment: read ms user experience guidelines. ENTER is for accepting and closing a dialog.

Comment: Cant go as per standard always, because we need to go as per requirements of users. Heavy data entry forms need enter key for navigation, this has been the practice since days of DOS and Unix. Just a spec created by some one at MS cannot change the whole practice. moreover, Also, check the meaning of "Enter" means and "Tab" in computer standards!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it depends on you

For a sample, you can place 4 textbox on the form and use the following code

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox2.Focus();
    }
}

private void textBox2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox3.Focus();
    }
}

private void textBox3_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox4.Focus();
    }
}
```

It might help you.

Happy coding...

Comment: @sqlchild, @Amol: To make it easier you could use a single OnKeyUp event and, using switch(...) on src control, you can decide which control Focus()...

Comment: its not working sir, do i have to do something with the tabindexes?

Comment: Generate the event from the form for each textbox's keyup. i think it should work. Try to place the controls again on the form.

Answer (score 1):

For example you could trap **OnKeyUp** event, check if it is RETURN and process source control to use **Focus()** to next control...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can fire the KeyDown or KeyUp event on a TextBox. To check whether it was the enter key, you can do the following:

```
//e is the KeyEventArgs from the event.
e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter
```

Then, if he has pressed the enter key, you can do:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SelectNextControl();
```

To set the order of your controls, in Visual Studio look for this little icon:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZWLO.png

Click it, and you'll go into tab ordering mode, as I like to call it. Just click the controls in the order you wish them to be and after you're done, click the little icon again. Presto!

Now whether that is a good idea of not, completely depends on how used to it your end users are. If they have always used it like this, and you give them something that doesn't fit into their mind model, they are going to say your software is broken.

Always always **always** try to emulate what processes the user already has in place in their head.

Read this if you have the time, it's a really light and very good read:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/fog0000000249.html

Comment: sir, SelectNextControl() is not coming in my IntelliSense? is it a version problem of .net framework?

Comment: @sqlchild: You can also do this instead, `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")` on the KeyDown or KeyUp event. It'll have the same end result.

Comment: SendKeys.Send("{TAB}") hints at the real solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to:

1) assign each textbox's TabIndex attribute incrementally (first is x, next is x+1 etc).

2) capture on the OnKeyUp event on the whole form, check the argument to see if the key was RETURN

3) focus the next textbox using its TabIndex. Or simulate the TAB key.

This code should work:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        GetNextControl((TextBox)sender, true);
    }
}
```

This way you end up writing only one function, and you can have as many textboxes as you want.