# How to override button click in c# (winForms)?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, button

Let me start with example:
I have `Form` with one button named **"btnTest"** and added `_click` event for it.

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("button click");
        }
```

Now I want to dynamically generate another `_click` event for this `button` using `Control` class and therefore override the existing `event_hendler`, so my form would look something like this:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Control[] controls = Controls.Find("btnTest", true); //find control by name
        controls[0].Click += Form1_Click; //generate button click
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("control click"); //want to be displayed
    }

    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        MessageBox.Show("button click");  //don't want to be displayed
    }
}
```

So my goal is to **enable** `Form1_Click` and to **ignore** `btnTest_Click` and to do so dynamically in code.
Done [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284232/disable-click-button-event-c-sharp) [research](https://forums.asp.net/t/1932626.aspx?How%20to%20override%20a%20click%20event%20in%20c%20), but couldn't get the answer.

**Why am i doing this?**

My main goal is to navigate through controls using **ENTER** keyword instead of **TAB**, so when I stumble on button I just want to move forward without triggering original event.

Note that `btnTest_Click` event is triggered before `Form1_Click` event and also bad solution would be to do something directly in`btnTest_Click` because I have limited amount of controls that I want to navigate using **ENTER** and hat is changeable, so the buttons I want to ignore would be in `controls` array.

Any suggestion is helpful, thank you for your time.

Comment: I would try to cancel the 13 on keydown event on the button, so click will only trigger when you hit space or click with the mouse or tap. as you surely don't want to make the button unclickable altogether.

Comment: This is an XY problem. You're set on a weird solution to solve something that does not actually need any enabling and disabling of these functions, just careful calling. Fairly sure you need to go to KeyDown for this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation in Windows Forms using enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605561/navigation-in-windows-forms-using-enter-key)

Comment: @dlatikay thank you for suggestion, and you are right about nnot wanting to make button unclickable

Comment: @MarkBenningfield thank you , but it is not a duplicate because I am not building navigation from start, i am just fixing exiting problem in code that has already been written

Comment: I am thinking a simple solution is to use a boolean flag every time you press the *enter* key. Then in your *btnTest_Click* event you just check if this flag is true.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε thank you for suggestion but that would not work in my case, because i am using multiple buttons and don't know which one will be used, and bad solution would be to check flag in all button clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle and research i've managed to find solution.
My logic is to remove all event hendlers before `controls[0].Click += Form1_Click;` and that would be the way to override original event.
Tried someting like this

```
 controls[0].Click += null;
 controls[0].Click += Form1_Click;
```

but it won't work, so i've found solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91853/7517846) answer, and my forum would look like this:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeComponent();
            Control[] controls = Controls.Find("btnTest", true); //find control by name
            Button btn = controls[0] as Button;    //safe cast as Button     
            RemoveClickEvent(btn); 
            controls[0].Click += Form1_Click; //generate button click
        }
        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("control click"); 
        }
        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("button click"); 
        }

        //remove all event hendlers for button 
        private void RemoveClickEvent(Button b)
        {
            FieldInfo f1 = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick",
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            object obj = f1.GetValue(b);
            PropertyInfo pi = b.GetType().GetProperty("Events",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            EventHandlerList list = (EventHandlerList)pi.GetValue(b, null);
            list.RemoveHandler(obj, list[obj]);
        }
```

Comment: this solution works but has one not so small issue, because click event is removed, button loses its functionality , so mouse click  won't work.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about this approach

```
Control control = Controls.Find("btnTest", true).FirstOrDefault(); //find control by name
if(control != null)
{
  btnTest.Click -= btnTest_Click; //Remove Default Event Handler.
  control.Click += Form1_Click; //generate button click
}
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion but it won't work, I can use `btnTest_Click` ,if somehow i can found that `btnTest_Click` name dynamically then this would work, this would be my logic but it needs to be dynamic, i have found solution and will post and answer, note that i've tried `controls[0].Click+=null; controls[0].Click += Form1_Click;` but it won't work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
controls[0].Click += Form1_Click;
controls[0].Click -= btnTest_Click;
```

Comment: can't do it, because it needs to be dynamic, i cant use `btnTest_Click` unless I found control by name like buban proposed

Comment: ok, if i understand your objetive, you need navigate with enterKey instead of
 TabKey, but you have a click event handle, so ,  i believe you can use PreviewKeyDown event handle and create a flag for detect if  Enterkey was pressed, then on the others events validate the flag and execute actions according to the flag's status, please view the example code:

Comment: this is nice thinking and thank you for your effort, but it won't work for me, it needs to be dynamic, let me try to explain, consider the following scenario: I have 17 buttons for navigation today , so i would neet to go and add this `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)` in al 17,  next day i have different 17 buttons for navigation so I need to do this `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)` again and delete from first 17.

Comment: How generate the 17 buttons? i going to modifly the code on answere, i try add 5 buttons on runtime, and add handle for Preview key press and Form1.Click, check this.