# Focus on next userControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, event-handling

I have a user control that have a number of textboxes and comboboxes contained in it.  These user controls are programmatically created and placed on a form.  The final user of this application want the ability to press enter an instead of going to the next child control in the usercontrol, they want to go to the equivilent textbox in the next usercontrol.

So essentially i want "Enter" to take focus from usercontrol1.textbox1 and place it in usercontrol2.textbox1.

Comment: this.ActiveControl.GetNextControl?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087786/press-enter-to-move-to-next-control