# Programmatically changed TAB key issue - c# window application

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, windows

I have set the "ENTER" key as a "TAB" key in windows form.

following is the code

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(keyData);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

its working perfectly with all controls but when I press ENTER on any combobox then it takes two tab indexes. 
eg.

1. textbox1
2. combobox
3. textbox2
4. textbox3
5. textbox4

when i press ENTER to leave combobox then the cursor(FOCUS) is directly comes to the textbox 3
i want that focus to the next control of combobox , i.e, textbox 2

please help me

thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `return true;` after you send the Tab:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(keyData);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            return true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Control.TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property decides that which order the control should get focused when a <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is pressed.

You should set `TabIndex` properties of controls in a order that you would like them to focus based on Tab key press.

That said, you shouldn't use `SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")` method for simulating a <kbd>Tab</kbd> key press. You should use [Control.SelectNextControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for this purpose.

Comment: thanks for reply, but can you please explain how to use Control.SelectNextControl method? i am new in this.

Comment: @Mr.Go You should be able to call `this.SelectNextControl(cc.ActiveControl, true, true, true, true);` not tested. See if that works. Or take a look at similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087786/press-enter-to-move-to-next-control

Comment: hey, it still won't work buddy. on combobox it take 2 tab... :(

Comment: What are the `TabIndex` set in your controls(textbox2, textbox3, ...)? Did you checked what are they?