# Changing focus of TextBoxes in a UserControl using the Enter key

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a custom `UserControl` that contains several `TextBoxe` controls, see below:

[image]

I would like to be able to use the `Enter` key to move between the `TextBoxe` controls in the `UserControl`.

However, when I place the `UserControl` on a form and hit the `Enter` key after the first `TexTbox` ('Shape') has the focus, the focus is placed on the next control of the form after the `UserControl`. It skips the 'Dim1' through 'Miscellaneous' `TextBoxe` controls. I can use the `Tab` key and it will move through each `TextBoxe` as expected.  I have tried using the different key-press events and while they catch certain keys (i.e. letters and numbers) they don't seem to catch the `Enter` key.

Any help/guidance on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Press Enter to move to next control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087786/press-enter-to-move-to-next-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to all text boxes in the user control a `KeyDown` event that catches `Enter` and sends focus do the next text box in the tab order:

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Control textbox = sender as TextBox;
    if (textbox != null) // Safety check
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // Check if next control is a text-box and send focus to it.
            Control nextControl = GetNextControl(textbox, true);
            if (nextControl is TextBox)
            {
                SelectNextControl(textbox, true, true, false, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To avoid event subscription as sugested by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant), you can override `ProcessCmdKey`:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    Control control = ActiveControl as TextBox;
    if (control != null) // Safety check
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // Check if next control is a text-box and send focus to it.
            Control nextControl = GetNextControl(control, true);
            if (nextControl is TextBox)
            {
                SelectNextControl(control, true, true, false, false);
            }
        }
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Do this in an override for ProcessCmdKey() instead so it works for all the controls without requiring an event subscription.  Use this.ActiveControl as the first argument to SelectNextControl.

Comment: Technically you also have to check the Multiline property.  But close enough.