# How can I enter data to Textboxes sequentially

Tags: c#

I'm a newbee to C# and I'm trying to write code in Visual Studio. I need your help.

I want to enter numbers to 20pcs textbox in tabpage1 in form by hand held barcode scanner in C#. Cursor must go to next textbox after reading from barcode scanner. And I will check the read data with some conditions (between 2 values numbers etc) for every textbox.

I write some code but it makes code size big. I think it must be easy way I need your comment and help.

The barcode scanner reads the barcode and sends barcode number + enter code. And barcode scanner read and put number to first textbox then pass to next textbox and it repeating for all textbox - how can I do this easily?

Thanks

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox1.SelectAll();
        textBox2.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox2.SelectAll();
        textBox3.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
.
.
.
.
private void textBox20_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        textBox20.SelectAll();
        textBox1.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: To reduce code you have to use same event handler for all textboxes. A neat *trick* to pass focus to next control is to simulate `Tab` keypress (see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1087786/1997232)). Otherwise you can store controls inside a `List<TextBox>` (or use `Controls` collection, or enumerate all controls and use their `Tag`) and use their index to find *next* control to call its `Focus()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is that the `sender` object is always that control which has triggered the event. In other words the `sender` is a reference to one of your `TextBox`s.

You can take advantage of this fact and you can have a single event handler, which could be reused for multiple events.

```cs
private void textBoxN_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        var textBoxCurrent = sender as TextBox;
        textBoxCurrent.SelectAll();
        //TODO: set focus for next 
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

So, the next question is how to get a reference to the next `TextBox`?
You can use the `Tag` property for this.

- In case of **WinForms** the `Control` object has a property called [Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netcore-3.1).
- In case of **WPF** the `FrameworkElement` object has a property called [Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=netcore-3.1).

In both cases this property is an `object` so we can store anything in that. If we populate that with a reference to the next `TextBox` then the generic handler would look like this:

```cs
private void textBoxN_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        var textBoxCurrent = sender as TextBox;
        textBoxCurrent.SelectAll();
        
        var textBoxNext = textBoxCurrent.Tag as TextBox;
        textBoxNext.Focus();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

What's left?

- Populate the `Tag` properties
- Subscribe to the `KeyDown` events

```cs
private void Init()
{
    var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { TextBox1, TextBox2, ..., TextBox20 };
    foreach(var item in textBoxes.Select((textBox, index) => (textBox, index))
    {
         var nextIdx = (item.index + 1) % textBoxes.Count;
         item.textBox.Tag = textBoxes[nextIdx];
         item.textBox.KeyDown += textBoxN_KeyDown;
    }

}
```

We have created an iterator here which is deconstructed into a `textbox` and an `index` of this `TextBox` in the `textBoxes` collection.

We have calculated the next `TextBox` index into the `nextIdx`. Then we have wired up everything.

Answer (score 0):

here is an idea for solving

```
class Program
{
    LinkedList<TextBox> _textBoxes;
    ctor()
    {
        _textBoxes = new LinkedList<TextBox>();
        _textBoxes.List.AddLast(textbox1);
        _textBoxes.List.AddLast(textbox20);
    }

    private void textBox_KeyDown_justOneCommonHandle(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            var textboxCurrent = _textBoxes.Current;
            // make sure that Value is the sender

            textboxCurrent.SelectAll();

            _textBoxes.MoveNext();
            var textboxNext = _textBoxes.Current;
            // check the end of list

            textboxNext.Focus();

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Marc_s, Peter Csala, Ivan Stavenchuk

Answer (score 0):

@ Peter Csala, @Ivan Stavenchuk
Thanks for your idea and help. I solved my problem as shown below

I added a main Textbox (textBox21) and used keydown event of main textbox

```
   private void textBox21_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Name = "textBox" + i.ToString();

       if (e.KeyCode==Keys.Enter)
        { 
        TextBox tbx = this.Controls.Find(tb.Name, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
        tbx.Text   = textBox21.Text ;
            i++;
            if (i>20) i=1;
            textBox21.SelectAll();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is quite error-prone. It relies on `string` manipulation not on strongly typed `TextBox` instances. That's why it is really fragile. For example if you mistype  the `Name` then `tbx` will be null because it won't find in the `Controls`, which will cause `NullReferenceException`. If a `Label` is named accidentally to `textBox1` yet again your cast fill return with `null`.  Etc. Try to avoid string based solutions.