# Tab enter controls asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have four text boxes positioned horizontally, if I type in TextBox1 and press <kbd>enter</kbd> I want to focus to next text box (i.e. I want tab event in <kbd>enter</kbd> Key), and so on ....

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the KeyPress event. If you are using WinForms, make sure you have set the KeyPreview property to True. There is a good example here: [How to Interpret an Enter KeyPress as a Tab in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626948/how-to-interpret-an-enter-keypress-as-a-tab-in-c)