# Use ENTER or RETURN as TAB in form and panels

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My form as multiple controls like `Textboxes` and `Panels`, and `Textboxes` in `Panels`, which cause problem. I try to make keys `ENTER` and `RETURN` do the same as `TAB`, so select next control, but for an unknown reason if I i go from any control to a panel, it doesn't enter the first control in the panel, it skips to the next control which isn't a panel.

My form `key preview` is already `True` and my tab index are okay :
First textbox is 10, first panel 11, first textbox of panel 12. For now it skips to 20, next textbox not in a panel.

Code based on this question : [Tab Key Functionality Using Enter Key in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406769/tab-key-functionality-using-enter-key-in-vb-net)

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Values_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Control, 
  ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If TypeOf Me.GetNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True) Is Panel Then
            Me.SelectNextControl(CType(Me.ActiveControl, Panel).Controls.Item(0), True, True, False, True)
        Else
            Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True, True, False, True)
        End If
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Hans' answer i manage to make it work by simply changing the nested parameter to true and get rid of the part that was suppose to make it work with panels, like this:

```
Private Sub Values_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Control, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Me.SelectNextControl(Me.ActiveControl, True, True, True, True)
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You'll still need to put the Key Preview parameter on your form to True

I also found an alternative here : [How to make Enter on a TextBox act as TAB button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11601550/8863031)

```
Private Sub Values_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Control, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Return Or e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand the code snippet, it looks like the last attempt before giving up.  Nor how it got to run at all, KeyPreview is not good enough to intercept KeyDown for the navigation keys like the Enter key.  The *nested* argument for SelectNextControl() should not certainly not be False, you do want to consider controls that are nested inside a panel as the next tab target, presumably what made the code jump off the rails.

I'll post a more universal solution that does not depend on KeyPreview and still properly deals with controls that need the Enter key to function correctly.  Simply copy/paste it into the form, it does not use events:

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    Dim dotab = False
    Dim ctl = Me.ActiveControl
    If ctl IsNot Nothing And keyData = Keys.Enter Then
        dotab = True
        If TypeOf ctl Is TextBoxBase Then
            If DirectCast(ctl, TextBoxBase).Multiline Then dotab = False
        End If
    End If
    If dotab Then
        If Me.SelectNextControl(ctl, True, True, True, True) Then Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Comment: Well, just changing nested argument for true did the work. I'll post my answer, but i didn't need to override anything to make it works. As i understand, making KeyPreview True for my form make me catch every key and key press events for anything on it, even controls. So how could this cause me problems catching Keydown events?

Comment: Well, you got two solutions in spite of the snippet, what's not to like.  Sooner or later you'll use a Rich/TextBox, you'll know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use processTabKey(true)  function