# How to make Enter Key as Default key for Tab Changing for all the textbox in a Window Form C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am using c# window form application. I have already tried many example on the internet for this query but nothing works for me. I just want to replace the action of Enter key with Tab key on a Window Forms. I don't want to apply keydown or up event on one by one on my textbox. I just want a single event which I can apply on my window form.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not working on Form_KeyPress Event. I just hear a bing sound nothing happened

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47680960/17034

Answer (score 0):

It works fine now I used these code of lines on form keyup event, and set the KeyPreview property True.

```
    if (e.KeyData == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter)
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        }
```

Comment: Because of `KeyPreview` the form can intercept events targeted to, for example, buttons. Which is undesirable. And the method `SendKeys.Send` can send a message to another application, if it is just at that time will receive the focus. Which is also undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom `TextBox`:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Parent.SelectNextControl(this, true, true, true, true);
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true; // suppress Ding sound
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Compile the code. This component will appear in the toolbar. Use it instead of the regular textboxes.